# Relabelling reference with link

Tags: bibliographies, citing, natbib, aliasing

Sorry if this is a repeat question, I have found it really difficult to even google what I am trying to do! As such I have to admit to not really having tried much myself as I dont even really know where to start.

In my text I make frequent reference to a bibtex item and as such have taken the standard procedure of writing "\cite{someone2020} (hereafter paper1)". Now I wish to do two things:

1. I would like it if I could have the text hyperlink every time I have "paper1" as if it was a regular bib item. That is it would jump to the relevant bib item if clicked on.
2. I would also like it if this could be put into a citation "group". So like \ref{someone2020, bob, betty, tom}" would give "paper1, Bob 1961, betty 2030, tom et al. 1945".

Hopefully this makes sense.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. How do you create the bibliography at present: by hand, or with a software tool such as BibTeX? If you use BibTeX, which bibliography style do you employ? Do you use a citation management package such as `natbib`?

Comment: Ah yes I probably should have said this! I use BibTex. The bibliography style (I am assuming this is the .bib file?) is from the MNRAS journal. I am not really sure what natbib is so I am going to say I probably do not. There is no \usepackage{natbib} in the document.

Comment: Then yes it is the journals own style. Monthly notices of the royal astronomical society (which is on overleaf), mnras.bib.

Answer (score 3):

The user guide of the `mnras` document class states -- cf. the left-hand column of page 2 -- that all papers that employ the `mnras` document class should specify the option `usenatbib`. Let's assume, then, that the first line in the OP's document is

```
\documentclass[usenatbib]{mnras}
```

The `mnras` document class recommends (but apparently does not *require*) use of the `mnras` bibliography style.

The `natbib` citation management package provides a straightforward way to "alias" citation call-outs. Suppose there's an entry with key `someone2020`. By placing the instruction

```
\defcitealias{someone2020}{paper1}
```

in the preamble, executing `\citetalias{someone2020}` in the body of the document produces `paper1`, and \citepalias{some2020} will produce `(paper1)`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[usenatbib]{mnras}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybib.bib}
@misc{someone2020,author="Anne Author",title="Thoughts",year=2020}
@misc{bob,author="Bob",title="Thoughts",year=2021}
@misc{betty,author="Betty",title="Thoughts",year=2022}
@misc{tom,author="Tom and Dick and Harry",title="Thoughts",year=2023}
\end{filecontents}
\bibliographystyle{mnras}

\setcitestyle{citesep={,}} % match the OP's citation callout preference
\defcitealias{someone2020}{paper1}

%\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
As argued in \citet{someone2020} (hereafter: \citetalias{someone2020}), \dots

\citep{someone2020, bob, betty, tom}

(\citetalias{someone2020}, \citealp{bob}, \citealp{betty}, \citealp{tom})
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ok first... I am stupid and you are right it is natbib I was looking for a usepackage when it was actually  where you said.

Second... This works!!! Thank you so much for this!